# Data in delta table is not changing with overwriting option?

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-storage, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am creating a delta table on top of a dataframe with external location. I was trying to overwrite delta table but data in delta table is getting overwrite but underlined data in delta lake gen2 is not changing. How can I overwrite delta table with data. Below is the code I used.

```
val tbl_snapshot_view=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header","true").load(s"${SourcePath}/tbl_snapshot")
```

creating delta table in datalake gen2

```
create table if not exists externaltables.tbl_snapshot(
id String,
typ_id String,
credttm String,
cdts String,
date String
)
using delta
location '/mnt/Storage/Silver/tbl_snapshot'
```

writing data into delta table

```
tbl_snapshot_view.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable(s"externaltables.tbl_snapshot")
```

Comment: how do you check that data doesn't change? Do you check for specific file names?

Comment: I was checking the data directly in data lake. The size of file and modified date are not changing.

Comment: can you explain more on "data in delta table is getting overwrite but underlined data in delta lake gen2 is not changing"?  did you mean that the data in the table is successfully overwritten, but data in '/mnt/Storage/Silver/tbl_snapshot' is not changed?

Comment: @PhuriChalermkiatsakul, Yes That is what happening.